# Hackthebox machine webpages not loading when entering IP address into search bar

Tags: browser, connection, ip

I wanted to do the starting point machines on HackTheBox and ran into a problem. I tried connecting to the webpage of 10.10.10.28 and it just keeps on loading forever with the note, that its 'waiting for 10.10.10.28'. If i ping the IP address it works fine. However I am able to load websites like Google even when typing their IP address into the search bar. I tried the EU and US openvpn from HackTheBox and also connecting to the port directly with 'http://10.10.10.28:80'. I hope you all have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely lies within your /etc/hosts file.
To fix this you need to add the given ip address of the box to it.
In the following image you can see an example:
[image: /etc/hosts file]

To do this you can do the following steps:

> sudo vim /etc/hosts

Use `i` in vim to insert text.

When finished adding your addresses, press "esc" use `:wq` to write and quit.

Comment: how we can find the ip address of the box?